# Numpy array assignment with copy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For example, if we have a `numpy` array `A`, and we want a `numpy` array `B` with the same elements.

What is the difference between the following (see below) methods? When is additional memory allocated, and when is it not?

1. `B = A`
2. `B[:] = A` (same as `B[:]=A[:]`?)
3. `numpy.copy(B, A)`

Answer (score 163, accepted):

All three versions do different things:

1. `B = A`

   This binds a new name `B` to the existing object already named `A`. Afterwards they refer to the same object, so if you modify one in place, you'll see the change through the other one too.
2. `B[:] = A` (same as `B[:]=A[:]`?)

   This copies the values from `A` into an existing array `B`. The two arrays must have the same shape for this to work. `B[:] = A[:]` does the same thing (but `B = A[:]` would do something more like 1).
3. `numpy.copy(B, A)`

   This is not legal syntax. You probably meant `B = numpy.copy(A)`. This is almost the same as 2, but it creates a new array, rather than reusing the `B` array. If there were no other references to the previous `B` value, the end result would be the same as 2, but it will use more memory temporarily during the copy.

   Or maybe you meant `numpy.copyto(B, A)`, which is legal, and is equivalent to 2?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: Numpy arrays work differently than lists do. Slicing an array does not make a copy, it just creates a new view on the existing array's data.

Comment: What is meant by `but B = A[:] would do something more like 1` ? According to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612815 `new_list = old_list[:]` is also a copy.

Comment: @mrgloom: Numpy arrays work differently than lists when it comes to slicing and copying their contents. An array is a "view" of an underlying block of memory where the numeric values are stored. Doing a slice like `some_array[:]` will create a new array object, but that new object will be a view of the same memory as the original array, which won't have been copied. That's why I said it's more like `B = A`. It takes only `O(1)` space and time, rather than the `O(n)` of each a real copy would need.

Comment: The preferred 'copy' method, according to the documentation, is `B = A.copy()`. However this form doesn't preserve order by default, you need `B = A.copy(order='k')`.

Answer (score 35):

1. `B=A` creates a reference
2. `B[:]=A` makes a copy
3. `numpy.copy(B,A)` makes a copy

the last two need additional memory.

To make a deep copy you need to use `B = copy.deepcopy(A)`

Comment: Refering to your second example: `B[:] = A` does **not** make a deep copy of arrays of object-type, e.g. `A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5]]); 
 B = np.array([None,None], dtype='O')`. Now try `B[:] = A;   B[0][0]=99`, this will change the first element in both **A and B**! To my knowledge, there is no other way to guarantee a deep copy, even of a numpy-array, than `copy.deepcopy`

Answer (score 17):

This is the only working answer for me:

```
B=numpy.array(A)
```