# Numpy assigning to slice, when is the array copied

Tags: python, numpy

So with numpy arrays assigning one to another just copies the reference:
i.e.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([5,8])
y = x 
y += 1
x
Out: array([6, 9])
```

And if I want a deep copy then I should use `x.copy()`. And the same is true when taking a view out of a higher dimensional array, e.g.

```
A=np.array([[4,10],[8,1]])
b=A[:,1]
b+=1
A
Out: array([[ 4, 11],
            [ 8,  2]])
```

And the other way round (continuing from above):

```
A[:,1]=b
b
Out: array([11,  2])
b+=1
A
Out: array([[ 4, 12],
            [ 8,  3]])
```

So up to here everything is working consistently. But now if I carry on and do:

```
A[:,0] = b
A
Out: array([[12, 12],
            [ 3,  3]])
b
Out: array([12,  3])
b+=1
A
Out: array([[12, 13],
            [ 3,  4]])
```

What I don't understand is why the first column stays the same and the other doesn't? Why does the second column continue to point to the b array? Is there any rule for deciding when an array will be deep copied on assignment?

Comment: I don't know for python, but It look like c++ pointer. You can assigned 1 memory space to multiple variable (like many variable read the same memory pointer) and not 1 variable to multiple memory space (1 var read multiple memory pointer)

Answer (score 8):

When you are doing

```
b=A[:,1]
```

it is creating a reference to the underlying array.
But in this case

```
A[:,0] = b
```

only values are copied.As a result in the last statement first column remains unchanged while second column which is still being referenced by b changes.
[Take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676538/numpy-array-assignment-with-copy)

Comment: Thanks.
And this reference isn't overwritten when I do 
    `A[:,1]=b` later?

And thanks for the link but I found that
    `B[:]=A`
also made a reference, rather than a separate copy.