# Why is the original image matrix values getting replaced?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, variables, image-processing

I am trying to threshold an image based on a hardcoded value.I am doing it by assigning the original image to a variable. This variable is used for thresholding. But, when I execute this, the original image is also getting thresholded. Am I doing something wrong? Or is there any other way to do this? The code is provided below:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imread
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
img1 = imread('4.2.04.tiff')
imgx = img1
imgx[img1>=150] = 0
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(np.uint8(img1))
plt.show()
plt.title('Original Image after thresholding')
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(np.uint8(imgx))
plt.title('Thresholded Image')
```

The images are provided below:
[image: Original Image]

[image: Original Image after thresholding]

[image: thresholded image]
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `imgx = img1`

You're basically creating a reference to the already existing variable `imgx`. Now `imgx` and `img1` point to the same address.

If you want to deep copy an array do this.

`img1 = numpy.array(imgx)`

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676538/numpy-array-assignment-with-copy#19676762) for details.

Comment: Also `imgx = img1.copy()` can create a deep copy and is a little more explicit, same with `numpy.copyTo(imgx, img1)`.