# Why does my numpy matrix get updated before get assigned?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

This is my code

```
import numpy as np
v = np.zeros(4)
backup = np.zeros(4)

for i in range(3):
   backup = v
   v[0] = 1
   print(backup)
```

My output is:

```
[1. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 0. 0. 0.]
```

But I expected:

```
[0. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 0. 0. 0.]
```

Why does backup matrix get updated before assignment?

Comment: Also, for reference: [Numpy array assignment with copy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19676538/3005167)

Answer (score 5):

You are not really doing *back up*: you are just making another reference.

Making a copy solves it:

```
import numpy as np
v = np.zeros(4)
backup = np.zeros(4)

for i in range(3):
    backup = v.copy()
    v[0] = 1
    print(backup)

[0. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 0. 0. 0.]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think backup = v is not making a copy its is just assigning the values.