# Copying numpy array with '=' operator. Why is it working?

Tags: python, numpy

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19676762/6740589) answer, `B=A` where `A` is a numpy array, `B` should be pointing to the same object `A`.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('rose.jpeg')
print("img.shape: ", np.shape(img))

img2 = img
img = cv2.resize(img, (250,100))
print("img.shape: ", img.shape)
print("img2.shape:", img2.shape)
```

Output:

```
img.shape:  (331, 500, 3)
img.shape:  (100, 250, 3)
img2.shape: (331, 500, 3)
```

It seems to be a very basic question, but I have been scratching my head over this. Could someone please explain what's happening behind it?

Comment: After `img = ...`, the name `img` refers to a new object, and `img2` still to the previous one. Have a look at https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "problem" is that your not using numpy here but opencv and while numpy array.resize() is in-place opencv img.resize() is not.

So your call to

```
    img = cv2.resize(img, (250,100))
```

creates a new object (image) with the given size. So here the img variable will point to a different object then before the call.

```
    img2 = img
```

adds a new name for the original object. Here img2 and img are refering to exactly the same object/piece of memory.

```
    img = cv2.resize(img, (250,100))
```

`cv2.resize(img, (250,100))` creates a new object and the name `img` now refers to that new object/piece of memory.

```
    print("img.shape: ", img.shape)
```

gets you the size of the new object and

```
    print("img2.shape:", img2.shape)
```

the size of the original object as img2 still refers to the original object.

By the way in numpy the call `a = a.resize(...)` would be really bad - because `a` would then by `None` (return value of `resize`) instead of the resized array. There you would just do `a.resize(...)`