# Issue with value assignment in python arrays

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I tried calculating the sum of each column in a 2D array O and stored it in 1D array col_sum.
But I see my array O getting updated automatically after updating array col_sum. Not able to figure out why. Please help.

OUTPUT:

Row 1 of array O: Before [ 14  83 236  55  58   9  64]

Updated col_sum [ 20 117 463 126 112  29 133]

Row 1 of array O: After [ 20 117 463 126 112  29 133]

```
import numpy as np

O = np.array([[14,83,236,55,58,9,64],[6,34,227,71,54,20,69]])
print('Row 1 of array O: Before', O[0])

row, col = O.shape

col_sum = O[0] # PROBLEM AREA

for i in range(row):
    for j in range (col):
        if i>0:
            col_sum[j] = col_sum[j] + O[i][j] #PROBLEM AREA - Why is array O getting updated?
            
            
print ('Updated col_sum', col_sum)
print ('Row 1 of array O: After', O[0])
```

Comment: Please provide an example output that you would like Thanks.

Comment: First you have a syntax error on the second to last line.

Comment: @Victor Sorry, it was a typo.. Added the output that I get.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `col_sum = np.copy(O[0])` to ensure updates to `col_sum` are not also reflected in `O`.

Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19676762/11778344 for a detailed explanation.