# copy of array gets overwritten in function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to create an array `np.zeros((3, 3))` outside a function and use it inside a function over and over again. The reason for that is `numba's` `cuda` implementation, which does not support `array creation` inside functions that are to be run on a `gpu`. So I create aforementioned array `ar_ref` , and pass it as argument to `function`. `ar` creates a copy of `ar_ref` (this is supposed to be used as "fresh" `np.zeros((3, 3))` copy). Then I perform some changes to `ar` and return it. But in the process `ar_ref` gets overwritten inside the function by the last iteration of `ar`. How do I start every new iteration of the function with `ar = np.zeros((3, 3))` without having to call `np.zeros` inside the `function`?

```
import numpy as np

def function(ar_ref=None):
    for n in range(3):
        print(n)
        ar = ar_ref
        print(ar)
        for i in range(3):
            ar[i] = 1
        print(ar)
    return ar

ar_ref = np.zeros((3, 3))
function(ar_ref=ar_ref)
```

Output:

```
0
[[0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]
[[1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]]
1
[[1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]]
[[1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]]
2
[[1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]]
[[1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List changes unexpectedly after assignment. How do I clone or copy it to prevent this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-how-do-i-clone-or-copy-it-to-prevent)

Comment: use copy methods . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676538/numpy-array-assignment-with-copy

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh although `np.copy` works, I am not sure if it is supported by the `numba.cuda` API. Is there a way to make a `slice copy` of an `array`? `ar = ar_ref[:]` produces the wrong result.

Comment: you can try `numpy.copy`, from the [second comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62834697/copy-of-array-gets-overwritten-in-function?noredirect=1#comment111115574_62834697)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple assignment will only assign pointer, so when you change `ar`, `ar_ref` changes too. try to use shallow copy for this issue

```
import numpy as np
import copy 

def function(ar_ref=None):
    for n in range(3):
        print(n)
        ar = copy.copy(ar_ref)
        print(ar)
        for i in range(3):
            ar[i] = 1
        print(ar)
    return ar

ar_ref = np.zeros((3, 3))
function(ar_ref=ar_ref)
```

output:

```
0
[[0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]
[[1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]]
1
[[0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]
[[1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]]
2
[[0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]
[[1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]]
```

Comment: If you need to work with the `numba.cuda` API `copy` might not be supported. `ar = ar_ref * 1` might be a better approach.